# How to make a request with another charset than UTF-8?

Tags: playframework, character-encoding

I use Play framework and WS, and need to make a http request encoded in ISO-8859-15. Where can I change the default encoding?? Every request is encoded in UTF-8.

It is for sending text messages, and the provider only accept messages encoded in ISO-8859-15

I tried to change the headers, encode the message only (it's then double url-encoded in utf-8...), and a few other things, but I have a hard time finding info on changing charset for RECENT versions of Play and WS.

```
...
    ws.url("https://api.smsmode.com/http/1.6/sendSMS.do")
      .addHttpHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-15")
      .addQueryStringParameters("message" -> message)
      .addQueryStringParameters("accessToken" -> accessToken)
      .addQueryStringParameters("numero" -> numero)
      .withMethod("GET")
      .stream().map { response =>
...
```

The message parameter should be encoded in ISO-8859-15, so the provider send the text message with accents.
Right now, the message is always incorrectly encoded, either in UTF-8 or double encoded.

Message: éèçà€@

Expected encoded request: %E9%E8%E7%E0%A4%40

Actuel encoded request: %C3%A9%C3%A8%C3%A7%C3%A0%E2%82%AC%40

Or, when double encoded: %25E9%25E8%25E7%25E0%25A4%2540

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I didn't find a way to make Play WS work with another charset, so I ended using scalaj-http, which have a nice ".charset" parameter.
It's not as nice as WS, but it works..

```
  def sms(
    message: String,
    accessToken: String,
    numero: String,
    classe_msg: String = "2",
    emetteur: String = "",
    notification_url: String = "",
    notification_url_reponse: String = ""
  ) = Action {

    val response = Http("https://api.smsmode.com/http/1.6/sendSMS.do")
      .param("message" , message)
      .param("accessToken" , accessToken)
      .param("numero" , numero)
      .param("classe_msg" , classe_msg)
      .param("emetteur" , emetteur)
      .param("notification_url" , notification_url)
      .param("notification_url_reponse" , notification_url_reponse)
      .charset("ISO-8859-1")
      .timeout(connTimeoutMs = 5000, readTimeoutMs = 5000)
      .asString
    response.code match {
      case 200 => Ok(response.body)
      case _ => BadGateway(response.body)
    }
  }
```